# What's the difference between android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION and the Google one?

Tags: android

I wanted to add `ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. I'm not sure which one I should use.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
```

or

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
```

Is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, we had to use the GMS one before Android 9 as it wasn't part of Android but only an addon of the Google Play Services.
Since Android 9, the feature has been added so Android now has a framework permission for it.

Comment: OK, but does it mean you need to specify both permissions in your app's manifest when targeting Android 12 for example?

Comment: If you cover Android < 9 then yes (again, my understanding)